# RewriteRule: internal redirect intended but got an external (301) redirect instead

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, httpd.conf, cloudflare

I am trying to do an internal redirect (i.e. the URL does not change) but I am unable to attain that.

**What I want to achieve:**
http://website.com/open/value1/value2 --- internal redirect to --> http://website.com/open?e=value1&lang=value2

**How I achieve it:**
In my httpd.conf, I have inserted a RewriteRule in the relevant VirtualHost section

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName website.com
ServerAlias website.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    <Directory /var/www/html>
           AllowOverride All
           Allow from all
           RewriteEngine On
           RewriteRule ^open/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /open?e=$1&lang=$2 [L,NC]
           RewriteRule ^open/([\w-]+)/?$ /open?e=$1&lang=en [L,NC]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**What goes wrong:**
The URL on the browser ends up changing to http://website.com/open?e=value1&lang=value2 (*which is the correct URL just that its external*). On my networks tab in Chrome, I notice the following:

General - Request URL: http://website.com/open/?e=Cosmoprof-Asia&lang=en
General - Status Code: 301 Moved Permanently
Response Headers - Location: https://website.com/open/?e=Cosmoprof-Asia&lang=en
Server: cloudflare-nginx

**Hypothesis**
• RewriteRule flags are incorrect
• Cloudflare is affecting my redirect
• Something else overrides it in httpd.conf

Comment: Do you mean an internal rewrite? I am not sure there is something like an internal redirect ;)

Comment: yup @ShubhamGoyal. want an internal mod_rewrite, no redirection